# #include file found in debug build but not in release build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a C++ (Brew C++) project in MVSC++ 10 which compiles in debug build but not in release build, but I cannot fathom out why not.

The problem is that header files within a certain directory cannot be found, the directory structure is:

```
.mak
.sln
etc.
/inc/A/m.h
/inc/B/n.h
/inc/C/o.h
/inc/util/html/a.h
/inc/util/html/b.h
/src/A/
/src/B/
/src/C/
/src/util/html/
```

i.e. the main project files are at the root directory and the header and source files distributed into sub folders.

a.h and b.h can be found in debug build but not found in release build.

Yet the .mak file contains:

```
....
INCDIRS := ....
$(ProjectDir)inc/A \
$(ProjectDir)inc/B \
$(ProjectDir)inc/util/html
```

So even though /inc/util/html is specified as an include directory in the .mak the project cannot find it - but only in release build.

There is no conditional behaviour between debug and relase builds that I can see - the header files are included within the source code irrespective of build configuration. And the above snippet is the only spot in the .mak file wehre the include directories are specified.

So why should there be a difference between the debug builds and release builds?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are the odds that you are actually building with the native MSVC build system instead of the .mak file?  You've got a .sln file.

Comment: If I edit the .mak i.e. remove the line $(ProjectDir)inc/B \
then it can't find any of the header files in inc/B - so the .mak is being utilized.

Comment: Look at your solution.  Do you actually have a Makefile project defined in it?

Comment: The .mak is visible in the Solution Explorer, if that is what you mean. If not what should I check?